# Volume using double integral method.

Tags: integration, area

So, I was given this question to find the volume of a general ellipsoid using the double integral method. Now what all the solutions did is they wrote everything in the form of

$z=c(\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}})$

and then used double integration to integrate it. Now what I don't understand is that I am not able to visually understand how this double integration works, because when they take one of the limits they just put $z=0$ and write $x$ in terms of $y$ and then integrate it. Can someone help me visualize how this all works? And can you also show me how will I write the triple integration to find the volume of the same?

I do not want the solution but rather just am confused about how writing the double integral of z.dx dy gave the actual volume of the ellipsoid.

Comment: The geometrical meaning of the double integral is the volume of a solid whose base is the domain in the $x, y$ plane, whose side is a cylindrical surface with generators parallel to the $z$-axis, and it is bounded above by the surface defined by $u =f(x, y)$. Can you notice these facts on a given example?

Comment: Oh, yeah, all of a sudden it clicked. Thanks!

Comment: @NgChungTak That does not help me because I already know how to do it. I was just confused about how the integral is working in this case.

Comment: @KutubkhanBhatiya That's temporary comment for close vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation of the solid ellipsoid $E$ seems to be in the OP notations:
$$
1\ge 
\frac {x^2}{a^2} + \frac {y^2}{b^2} + \frac {z^2}{c^2} \ ,
\qquad a,b,c>0\ .
$$
It is clear that the ellipsoid is inside the "box"
$[-a,a]\times[b,-b]\times[c,-c]$.

So $z\in [-c,c]$. Now fix one special value $z_0$ in the domain of variation.
Then the possible values of $x,y$ so that $(x,y,z_0)$ is in the region $E$ are constrained to $x^2/a^2+y^2/b^2\le 1-z_0^2/c^2$.

Visually, cut the solid ellipsoid $E$ with the plane $z=z_0$, the intersection is the region inside an ellipse, it is exactly the inequation above for $(x,y)$.
This is a constraint for  $x,y$ so let us let $y$ first run in the possible interval, which is the interval between $-b\sqrt(1-z_0^2/c^2)$ and
$+b\sqrt(1-z_0^2/c^2)$. Fix now some $y_0$ in this interval. Then $x$ is constrained to $x^2/a^2\le 1- y_0^2/b^2-z_0^2/c^2$.
So a possible $x_0$ is only between
$-a\sqrt(1- y_0^2/b^2-z_0^2/c^2)$ and
$+a\sqrt(1- y_0^2/b^2-z_0^2/c^2)$.

Fubini allows now to write the volume $V$ to be computed as follows:
$$
\begin{aligned}
V&=\iiint_E 1\cdot dx\; dy\;dz\\
&=\int_{-c}^c
dz
\int_{-b\sqrt(1-z^2/c^2)}^{b\sqrt(1-z^2/c^2)}
dy
\int_{-a\sqrt(1-y^2/b^2-z^2/c^2)}^{a\sqrt(1-y^2/b^2-z^2/c^2)}
dx
\\
&=\int_{-c}^c
dz
\int_{-b\sqrt(1-z^2/c^2)}^{b\sqrt(1-z^2/c^2)}
dy\; 2a\sqrt{1-\frac {y^2}{b^2}-\frac {z^2}{c^2}}
\\[3mm]
&\qquad\text{Substitution: $z=c\sin t$ and $y=b\cos t\sin s$, 
             with $s,t\in[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$}
\\[3mm]
&=
\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} c\cos t\; dt
\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} b\cos t\cos s\; ds
\cdot 
2a\cos t\cos s
\\
&=2abc
\left(\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\cos ^3 t\; dt\right)
\left(\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\cos ^2 s\; ds\right)
\\
&=2abc\cdot \frac 43\cdot \frac \pi 2=\frac{4\pi}3abc\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
This specializes to the (better) known volume of the sphere with radius $R$, in case of $a=b=c=R$.

*Note:* (Edit after the question in the comments.) The $n$-dimensional volume of a region in $\Bbb R^n$ is obtained by integrating the constant function $1$ on that region w.r.t. the usual measure of the euclidean space. Sometimes this one-function is no longer mentioned as a matter of notation, convention.

Comment: I did understand, I am just confused about one thing, why do we write 1 dx dy dz. Is it because dx dy dz is dV, and that is what we are looking for, right?

Comment: To @KutubkhanBhatiya: True. In other words, volume of a solid, i.e. $V=\int_V \mathrm dV = \iiint_V \mathrm dx \mathrm dy \mathrm dz$, is just one of applications of the triple integral.